# Proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to prove, using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic and contradiction, that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational. Here is my attempt.

> Suppose otherwise that $\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Q}$, so there exists $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $b \neq 0$ such that $\sqrt{2} = \frac{a}{b}$. Without loss of generality, we can assume $a,b > 0$ since $q^2 = (-q)^2$, and that $a$ and $b$ have no common factors. Then $2 = \frac{a^2}{b^2}$, so $2b^2 = a^2$. By the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, $a$ and $b$ can be factored uniquely as a product of primes. Let $M$ be the number of prime factors, with multiplicity, of $a$ and $N$ the number of prime factors, with multiplicity, of $b$. Then $a^2$ and $b^2$ have $2M$ and $2N$ prime factors, with multiplicity. As $2$ is prime, $2b^2$ has $2N + 1$ prime factors with multiplicity, which is not even. That is, with multiplicity, $a^2$ has an even number of prime factors and $2b^2$ has an odd number of prime factors, contradicting the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

How does this proof look?

Comment: From the [tag:solution-verification] tag description: *"This should not be the only tag for a question."*

Comment: @Shaun My apologies. Would you classify this problem as number theory?

Comment: It's alright. You're new. Elementary number theory is fine.

Comment: The argument is fine.  Note that you really only need to focus on the order to which $2$ divides both sides.  $2$ divides $a^2$ an even number of times, $2$ divides $2b^2$ an odd number of times.  To be sure, we need Unique Factorization to demonstrate that the "order",  in this sense, is well defined.

Comment: Although the proof is fine, it’s more complicated than the standard proof. The fundamental theorem of arithmetic is a much more complicated theorem than that the root 2 is irrational

Comment: Also, if you are going to use the overpowered fundamental theorem, you could make it even simpler. In particular, $2=a^2/b^2=2^1$ has no primes to the negative power, and any prime $p$ that divides $b$ would be negative in any prime factorization, so $b^2=1$, so $a^2=2$. Since $a^2$ is either 0,1, or at least 4, it isn’t $2$ giving the desired contradiction

Comment: This is almost exactly the proof that I prefer.

Comment: It is correct, and is one of the most common proofs, and it doesn't require high-powered  unique prime factorization, as explained in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2441234/242) in the linked dupe.

Comment: But, to be completely rigorous, one must *explicitly* invoke FTA (existence and uniqueness of prime factorizations) in the several places where it is implicitly used. For more on this see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3330090/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/638530/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/222184/242).